# How can I implement recursive backtracking for this sudoku solver without using any for loops?

Tags: python, recursion, recursive-backtracking

I am trying to create a sudoku solver that uses recursive backtracking, however, I am not using any for loops in my program. This makes it difficult since when using the backtracking method, I need to use a for loop to iterate through the guesses from 1 to 9. Can anyone tell me how I can fix my recursive helper function that generates valid guesses?

```
def solve_sudoku(puzzle):
    # solve sudoku using backtracking technique
    # our puzzle is a list of lists, with each inner list being a row
    # return whether a solution exists
    # if solution exists, solution is printed in main portion of code

    # step 1: choose somewhere to make a guess (iterates through puzzle looking for 0, which is a blank)
    row, column = find_next_empty(puzzle)

    # step 1.1: if there are no remaining empty spots, we must be done
    if row is None:
        return True
    
    # generate a guess 
    trial = guess(puzzle, row, column)

    # if there was no valid guess available, and guess() returned 0
    if trial == 0:
        return False

    print(str(trial) + ' was placed.')
    
    # update the board by placing the valid guess
    puzzle[row][column] = trial
    
    # recursively call the solver
    if solve_sudoku(puzzle):
        return True

    # backtracking portion (this is the portion that I do not think is functioning properly)
    puzzle[row][column] = 0
    
    # return False if no solutions to the puzzle
    return False
    

# create function to recursively guess from 1 - 9, return the valid guess value
def guess(puzzle, row, column, n = 1):
    # stopping condition
    if n > 9:
        return 0
    # is_valid() function is working properly, basically returns True if the same number does not exist in same row, column or 3x3 matrix
    if is_valid(puzzle, n, row, column):
        return n
    return guess(puzzle, row, column, n + 1)
```

Output Images:
[Input Board where 0s represent blanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kAwm.png)

[My Board's output which returns False after failing to find a solution for the last blank on row 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlmni.png)

[Expected Output where board is fully solved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUS9w.png)

Comment: Are you allowed to use other forms of loops? For example, `while`?

Comment: Nope, anything that involves loops would require a recursive helper function :(